# Dataflow parallel pipeline

Tags: pipeline, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I need to realize a job dataflow with parallel pipelines (one for each entity found in a file configuration.json).
The first step is to read an event from pub/sub that notifies file arriving for an entity on a bucket GCS. After reading and parsing the message, the file is taken from GCS and the content is pushed to the entity topic.
This is my implementation:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import json
import csv
import apache_beam.io.fileio as fileio
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


def read_csv_file(readable_file):
 with beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open(readable_file) as gcs_file:
   for row in csv.reader(gcs_file):
     yield row

def run():
   options = PipelineOptions(
       project='XXX',
       runner='DataflowRunner',
       streaming=True,
       job_name='dataflow-job',
       staging_location='gs://dataflow-bucket-at/staging',
       temp_location='gs://dataflow-bucket-at/temp',
       region='europe-west8'
   )

   with open('./conf/configuration.json', 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
       pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
       
       for entity in data['entities'][0].keys():

         ( pipeline
            | "Read from pubsub_{}".format(entity) >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=f"projects/XXX/subscriptions/topic_events_{entity}_sub")
            | "Parse messages_{}".format(entity) >> beam.Map(lambda message: json.loads(message))
            | "Extract file_path_{}".format(entity) >> beam.Map(lambda message: message.get('filePath'))  # Extract the value of 'file_path' from the dictionary
            | "Filter message_{}".format(entity) >> beam.Filter(lambda e: e.split('.')[0] == entity)
            | "Find CSV_{}".format(entity) >>  fileio.MatchFiles(f"gs://input_files_at/{entity}.csv") # emits FileMetadatas
            | "Read CSV_{}".format(entity) >> beam.FlatMap(read_csv_file)                          # emits rows
            | "Parse CSV_{}".format(entity) >> beam.Map(lambda line: line.split(","))
            | "Publish message_{}".format(entity) >> beam.io.WriteToPubSub(f"projects/XXX/topics/topic_{entity}")
         )
       
       pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   run()
```

In the configuration.json I have two entities so I'm expecting two parallel branches in the job Dataflow.

Instead this is the result:
[Dataflow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEZnc.png)

Can you help me please?

Comment: You basically have two sources for one entity (pub/sub and file io). They cannot be chained. I think you might need use side_input to get the entity first and then pass it into the fileio.MatchFiles.